# Can't find entry file when deploying node app to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my first node app to heroku. I have set up a `Procfile` with the following code

```
web: node ./app/server.js
```

but when I deploy to heroku and check the logs I see the error `Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'`.

On local it works fine. I have the following in my `package.json` nested under `scripts`

```
"start": "nodemon ./app/server.js
```

Comment: in local script you have `nodemon` and in procfile `node` ?

Comment: Yes, is that a problem? New to the node environment.

Comment: Nodemon is a utility that will monitor for any changes in your source and automatically restart your server. Perfect for development. check your file  path for server.js once again.

Comment: I switched it to `web: nodemon ./app/server.js` it successfully built then made a bunch of get request then it tried to run `Starting process with command `node server.js`` and failed with the same error as above. I do not have `node server.js` anywhere.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but I'm not following. I can change update my folder structure but why?

Comment: Replace your `start` script command with `node ./app/server.js` and try deploying. This will work.

Comment: Aww that makes sense and it worked but now I get the error in the console that it couldn't find my `bundle.js` file. Is this because it's on my `.gitignore` should I remove it and push it up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154940/discussion-between-kgangadhar-and-jstuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nodemon` is a utility that will monitor for any changes in your source and automatically restart your server. Perfect for development.

While using nodemon its better to maintain script commands for `dev` and `production` as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./app/server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon ./app/server.js"
  }
```

To determine how to start your app, The deployment server( `Heroku`) first looks for a `Procfile`. If no `Procfile` exists for a `Node.js` app, It will attempt to start a default web process via the `start` script in your `package.json`.

If you use `nodemon` in script, It'll internally try to run `node server.js` but in your case start file present in `app/server.js`. To avoid these issues it's better to use two separate script commands for `dev` and `production`. So that while running locally you can use `npm dev` command.